# Proof without words for the sum and product of three tangents

Tags: trigonometry

How to get the $\tan\beta \tan\gamma$ in the third picture?

[image: Proof without words for the sum and product of three tangents]

The image is original from MAA
https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/321918646676.pdf.bannered.pdf

Comment: The hypotenuse is the same and they've just rearranged the terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(If you're asking about the picture labelled $2$, although it is the third diagram.) 
If you scale the triangle, the angles don't change. Scale it such that the side becomes $\tan\beta \tan \gamma$.

If you don't like it that way, replace $\tan\beta \tan \gamma$ with $k\tan\beta \tan \gamma$. In the end, you can still prove the claim.